# Need some help porting this C code to C#

Tags: c#, c, compression

I am not very good at c at all. I have tried to capture the essense of what the C code does in C# using this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) article. However my version is totally different and does not achive the same compression that the C code does. Therefore, I'd like to port the following code from C to C#. However, i do not need it to read/write to files.

I am not familiar with how file reading and writing works in C. Therefore all of the file related fluff confuses me. Also these lines are a little confusing: `token = i - 1 | 0x80;` and `length = (token & ~0x80) + 1;`

```
/******************************************************************************
 * LoadRLE / SaveRLE - Load and save binary data using RLE compression.
 *  Run-length tokens have a set MSB, while data tokens have a cleared
 *  MSB. The value of the token's remaining bits plus one indicates the
 *  length of the block. The minimum run length is three bytes, while
 *  the maximum is 128.
 *
 *  data - Array holding data to load or save.
 *  size - Size of the data array.
 *  file - The file pointer to use.
 *  return - Total number of bytes read from or written to data[].
 */
size_t SaveRLE (unsigned char data[], size_t size, FILE *file)
{
    unsigned char token;
    unsigned int i;
    size_t total = 0;

    while(size)
    {
        /*This loop identifies blocks of repeating data:*/
        i = 2;
        while(i < size && i < 128 &&
            data[i] == data[i - 1] && data[i - 1] == data[i - 2])
            i++;
        /*If repeating data was found, save it:*/
        if(i > 2){
            token = i - 1 | 0x80;
            if(!fwrite(&token, 1, 1, file))
                return total;
            if(!fwrite(data, 1, 1, file))
                return total;
            data += i, size -= i, total += i;
        }

        /*This loop identifies blocks of non-repeating data:*/
        i = 0;
        while(i < size && i < 128 && (i + 2 > size ? 1 :
            data[i] != data[i + 1] || data[i + 1] != data[i + 2]))
            i++;
        /*If non-repeating data was found, save it:*/
        if(i){
            token = i - 1;
            if(!fwrite(&token, 1, 1, file))
                return total;
            if(fwrite(data, 1, i, file) != i)
                return total;
            data += i, size -= i, total += i;
        }
    }

    return total;
}

size_t LoadRLE (unsigned char data[], size_t size, FILE *file)
{
    unsigned char token;
    unsigned int length;
    size_t total = 0;

    while(size && fread(&token, 1, 1, file)){
        length = (token & ~0x80) + 1;
        if (length > size)
            return total;
        if(token & 0x80){
            if(!fread(&token, 1, 1, file))
                return total;
            memset(data, token, length);
        }else{
            if(fread(data, 1, length, file) != length)
                return total;
        }
        data += length, size -= length, total += length;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mike, you will have to make a bigger effort. SO won't write chunks of code for you. Learn C, learn C# and then *just do it*.

Comment: Please read my post again. I am simply asking for help with specific parts. If you do not have the time to read the post then please don't leave a comment saying learn C and C#. It is not very helpful at all.

Comment: Why are people upvoting Eli's comment? He clearly didn't read past the question's title.

Comment: Make sure you refactor those `while` loops into something a bit more readable.

Comment: @Quick Joe: the OP seems to be asking for a code review or rewrite.  I don't see much in the way of a real question.  I see 63 lines of code **not** related to the OP's specific question, and "all of the file related fluff confuses me".

Comment: It is still an entirely unhelpful and misguided comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* 0 */
unsigned char token;
unsigned char data[];
FILE *file;

/* 1 */
if(!fwrite(&token, 1, 1, file))
    return total;

/* 2 */
if(!fwrite(data, 1, 1, file))
    return total;

/* 3 */
if(fwrite(data, 1, i, file) != i)
    return total;

/* 4 */
if(!fread(&token, 1, 1, file))
    return total;

/* 5 */
if(fread(data, 1, length, file) != length)
    return total;

/* 6 */
while(size && fread(&token, 1, 1, file))

/* 7 */
data += i;
data[i];
```

```
/* 0 */
int token; // I'm using 'int' here to easier read single byte from Stream object, in your C code 'token' variable does not overflow so there will be no problem with that is has other type then 'byte'
byte[] data;
int data_pos = 0; // instead of moving 'data' pointer use additional index variable
Stream file; // some stream to read/write bytes

try {
    /* 1 */
    file.WriteByte((byte)token);

    /* 2 */
    file.Write(data, data_pos, 1);

    /* 3 */
    file.Write(data, data_pos, i);

    /* 4 */
    if ((token = file.ReadByte()) < 0)
        return total;

    /* 5 */
    if (file.Read(data, data_pos, length) < length)
        return total;

    /* 6 */
    while((size != 0) && ((token = file.ReadByte()) >= 0))

    /* 7 */
    data_pos += i;
    data[data_pos + i];

} catch (IOException e) {
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For your file question, I would strongly suggest consulting the C standard library documentation.

[fread](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) [fwrite](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite)

```
token = i - 1 | 0x80;
```

i minus 1, | does a bitwise OR operation, in this case setting the 8th bit in token.

```
length = (token & ~0x80) + 1;
```

`token & ~0x80` takes the NOT of 0x80 (all bits but the high bit) and does a bitwise AND (bit is set when both bits are set). In this case, it returns every but but the 8th bit.

As for what this means in your case, look at some articles about RLE.

Comment: Thankyou for clearing some things up for me. Those links helped. However, I should have explained myself a little more. I am not confused with the bitwise operations. I am confused about the choice of 128 or 0x80 and why it is or'd with i-1.

Comment: That is specific to their implementation of RLE: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding .. It looks like the high bit is used to signal a repetition token in this version.

Comment: Small note: the comment included with the code in the question explains _exactly_ how this RLE implementation works. All you need to know is that MSB = Most Significant Bit = highest bit = 0x80

Answer (score 1):

```
token = i - 1 | 0x80;
```

The `|` symbol is a bitwise OR, so it is combining `i - 1` with `0x80` (hex for 128). I will leave the research into bitwise operations to you.

```
length = (token & ~0x80) + 1;
```

The `&` is a bitwise AND, while `~` negates the following value (flips the 1s and 0s). So that:

```
~1111000 = 00001111
```

Incidentally, all these operators are in C# and work in more or less the same way.